# Cannot install any extensions in VSC, failed to install download manually

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to install extensions in VSC but each of them fail, the following message appears when attempting to install an extension:

> failed to install download manually

Error in VSCode

[image: Error preview]

Comment: Are you using proxy server for internet?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how this happened, but I ran into the same issue. I just checked the output of `Log (Shared)` in the vs code terminal, and I saw the following:

```
[2019-10-04 11:53:59.071] [sharedprocess] [info] Installing extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml
[2019-10-04 11:53:59.075] [sharedprocess] [error] Failed to install extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/sgtpooki/.vscode/extensions/.obsolete'
[2019-10-04 11:53:59.343] [sharedprocess] [info] Installing extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml
[2019-10-04 11:53:59.345] [sharedprocess] [error] Failed to install extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/sgtpooki/.vscode/extensions/.obsolete'
[2019-10-04 11:53:59.627] [sharedprocess] [info] Installing extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml
[2019-10-04 11:53:59.630] [sharedprocess] [error] Failed to install extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/sgtpooki/.vscode/extensions/.obsolete'
[2019-10-04 11:53:59.771] [sharedprocess] [info] Installing extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml
[2019-10-04 11:53:59.776] [sharedprocess] [error] Failed to install extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/sgtpooki/.vscode/extensions/.obsolete'
[2019-10-04 11:54:00.034] [sharedprocess] [info] Installing extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml
[2019-10-04 11:54:00.036] [sharedprocess] [error] Failed to install extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/sgtpooki/.vscode/extensions/.obsolete'
[2019-10-04 11:54:00.184] [sharedprocess] [info] Installing extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml
[2019-10-04 11:54:00.186] [sharedprocess] [error] Failed to install extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/sgtpooki/.vscode/extensions/.obsolete'
[2019-10-04 11:54:00.472] [sharedprocess] [info] Installing extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml
[2019-10-04 11:54:00.475] [sharedprocess] [error] Failed to install extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/sgtpooki/.vscode/extensions/.obsolete'
[2019-10-04 11:54:00.760] [sharedprocess] [info] Installing extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml
[2019-10-04 11:54:00.762] [sharedprocess] [error] Failed to install extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/sgtpooki/.vscode/extensions/.obsolete'
[2019-10-04 11:54:00.911] [sharedprocess] [info] Installing extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml
[2019-10-04 11:54:00.914] [sharedprocess] [error] Failed to install extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/sgtpooki/.vscode/extensions/.obsolete'
[2019-10-04 11:54:01.174] [sharedprocess] [info] Installing extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml
[2019-10-04 11:54:01.176] [sharedprocess] [error] Failed to install extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/sgtpooki/.vscode/extensions/.obsolete'
[2019-10-04 11:54:01.381] [sharedprocess] [info] Installing extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml
[2019-10-04 11:54:01.383] [sharedprocess] [error] Failed to install extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/sgtpooki/.vscode/extensions/.obsolete'
```

Idk what this file is, but I checked, and it had the following permissions:

```
 $ ls -lhatr /Users/sgtpooki/.vscode/extensions
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   3 sgtpooki  ANT\Domain Users    96B Jul 17 11:39 ..
drwxr-xr-x  11 sgtpooki  ANT\Domain Users   352B Aug  1 12:39 orta.vscode-jest-3.0.2
drwxr-xr-x  11 sgtpooki  ANT\Domain Users   352B Aug 14 21:18 esbenp.prettier-vscode-1.9.0
drwxr-xr-x  11 sgtpooki  ANT\Domain Users   352B Aug 16 15:45 jvandyke.vscode-circleci-0.5.0
drwxr-xr-x  11 sgtpooki  ANT\Domain Users   352B Aug 20 12:58 dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-1.9.1
drwxr-xr-x  19 sgtpooki  ANT\Domain Users   608B Aug 21 16:18 gruntfuggly.todo-tree-0.0.142
drwxr-xr-x  11 sgtpooki  ANT\Domain Users   352B Aug 21 16:18 fabiospampinato.vscode-github-notifications-bell-2.3.0
drwxr-xr-x  26 root     ANT\Domain Users   832B Aug 22 16:00 jebbs.plantuml-2.11.2
drwxr-xr-x  15 root     ANT\Domain Users   480B Aug 23 12:18 esbenp.prettier-vscode-1.10.0
drwxr-xr-x  10 root     ANT\Domain Users   320B Aug 23 13:11 myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml-1.0.4
drwxr-xr-x  12 sgtpooki  ANT\Domain Users   384B Aug 23 13:11 .
-rw-r--r--   1 root     ANT\Domain Users    37B Aug 26 11:14 .obsolete
```

So I deleted it.. then I tried installing the extension again:

```
[2019-10-04 11:54:13.024] [sharedprocess] [info] Starting to clean up unused language packs.
[2019-10-04 11:55:20.951] [sharedprocess] [info] Installing extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml
[2019-10-04 11:55:23.088] [sharedprocess] [info] Downloaded extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml /var/folders/0j/swbv2kwd7mgbhtp39k6dk94w277jgc/T/4288560a-75a5-4066-ba05-44cdbd470e3a
[2019-10-04 11:55:23.115] [sharedprocess] [error] Failed to install extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml Unable to delete the existing folder '/Users/sgtpooki/.vscode/extensions/myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml-1.0.4' while installing the extension 'myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml'. Please delete the folder manually and try again
```

soo... then I deleted that folder:

```
sudo rm -rf /Users/sgtpooki/.vscode/extensions/myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml-1.0.4
```

Then I tried installing the extension again and **it worked.**

```
[2019-10-04 11:56:02.127] [sharedprocess] [info] Installing extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml
[2019-10-04 11:56:02.472] [sharedprocess] [info] Downloaded extension: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml /var/folders/0j/swbv2kwd7mgbhtp39k6dk94w277jgc/T/7fd93d6c-a5eb-4191-8935-cd7f349a769a
[2019-10-04 11:56:03.052] [sharedprocess] [info] Extracted extension to /Users/sgtpooki/.vscode/extensions/.myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml-1.0.4: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml
[2019-10-04 11:56:03.053] [sharedprocess] [info] Renamed to /Users/sgtpooki/.vscode/extensions/myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml-1.0.4
[2019-10-04 11:56:03.054] [sharedprocess] [info] Installation completed. myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml
[2019-10-04 11:56:03.094] [sharedprocess] [info] Extensions installed successfully: myxvisual.vscode-ts-uml
```

I have no idea how I got into this state, but I did, and out of all of the similar issues found online, no one else seems to have run into this particular version, but hopefully this helps you solve your issue.

At the very least, check the output tab in the vs code terminal, and toggle the different terminals in the top right:

[image: vscode output terminal, context selection]

Comment: This worked!  Every folder VSCode complained about, I deleted and then re-opened VSCode so that extensions could properly install again.

Comment: This worked for me as well. For those confused: just look in your personal folder (the one with Documents, Music, and Downloads folders) and you should see the ".vscode" folder. (Mine was hidden, but I may have done that myself.)

Comment: Deleting the `.obsolete` file fixed my issue too. The .obsolete file listed a python plugin I had installed and a yaml plugin: `ms-python.python-2020.8.101144` and `redhat.vscode-yaml-0.9.1`

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Control Panel > Network and Sharing Center > Choose Change Adapter Settings (On the left)
2. Choose the network you're using (Your WiFi or Ethernet)
3. Go to properties > Choose Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)
4. Choose the following DNS server adresses:

   - Prefered DNS server  : `8.8.8.8`
   - Alternate DNS server : `8.8.4.4`
5. Press OK and find Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)
6. Choose the following DNS server adresses:

   - Prefered DNS server  : `2001:4860:4860::8888`
   - Alternate DNS server : `2001:4860:4860::8844`
7. Press OK and one more OK to save these changes

This will fix the problem